# Break operator with continue c++

Tags: c++, break, continue

My code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n; 
    int total = 0;
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> n;
    while (total + n <= 1000)
    {
        cout << total << " ";
        total = n + total;
        continue;
    }
}
```

I need to add the following condition: if int n<0 program must close with a break operator

Comment: I suggest testing your code before expanding it further. You might find it doesn't work as expected (unless it is expected that user only enters one number in the whole program).

Comment: "program must close with a break operator" it is unclear what you mean by that. `if (n <0) return 0;` after taking input ?

Comment: That `continue;` doesn't do anything. The loop ends at the `}` immediately after it, so the behavior would be exactly the same without the `continue;`. `continue` skips code that follows it. If there's no code following it, it isn't needed.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yep, it is expected that user only enters one number in the whole program

Comment: You should add a description of what the program is supposed to do then, my first guess was that it's supposed to read numbers in a loop until the sum exceeds 1000.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break out of the `while` loop you can use something like this:

```
while (total + n <= 1000)
    {
        cout << total << " ";
        total = n + total;
        if (n < 0) break;
    }
```

But because variable `n` does not change in the loop I suggest you use `return` before the while loop:

```
int n; 
int total = 0;
cout << "Enter a value: ";
cin >> n;
if (n < 0) return 0;
while(...){
...
}
```